# Solving another discrete ODE with generating function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Given the discrete ODE: $$\dot{\rho}_n(t) = -g \,\rho_n(t) +  g\,\rho_{n-1}(t)$$

I'm advised solving this with a generating function $G(s,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s^n\,\rho_n$

It should hold: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^n\,\rho_{n-1} = G(s,t)\cdot s+ \rho_{-1}$ thus by substituting into the ODE:

$$\dot{G} = -g\,G+ g\,s\cdot G + g\,\rho_{-1}$$

Solving brings:

$$G = {C}\,e^{\textstyle (g\,s-g)\,t} + \dfrac{g\,\rho_{-1}}{(g\,s-g)}$$

---

However something feels utterly weird about this. Also I have no clue how this helps with finding $\rho_n(t)$. Just as little how to incorporate the initial condition $\rho_n(0) = \delta_{n0}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Laplace transform

$$
(s+g)\hat \rho_n(s) = \hat \rho_{n-1}(s)+\rho_n(0) = \hat \rho_{n-1}(s)+\delta_{n,0}
$$

so

$$
\hat \rho_n(s) = \left(\frac{g}{s+g}\right)^n \Rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{-1} [\hat \rho_n(s)] = \frac{g^n t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-g t}
$$

NOTE

Regarding the generating function method, a hint:

$$
e^{(-g+gs)t} = e^{-gt}e^{g s t} = e^{-g t}\sum_k\frac{g^kt^k}{k!}s^k = \sum_k\left(e^{-g t}\frac{g^kt^k}{k!}\right)s^k
$$

Defining $G(s,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho_n(t)s^n$ we have

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}G = -g G + g s G\Rightarrow G(s,t) = C e^{-g t}e^{s g t}
$$

now, as $G(s,0) = 1$ follows $C=1$ so $G(s,t) = e^{-g t}e^{s g t}$

Comment: Interesting technique but how do I get it with the method above?

Comment: Are you referring to the generating function technique?

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Comment: Thank you for the Note! As I stated I am lacking some advanced knowledge. So to clear some things off: Is the Generating Function $G$ right at all? How to deal with the $\rho_{-1}$ thing? Finally how to include the initial condition? Afterwards I might be able to follow.

Comment: Note that $\rho_n(0) = \delta(n-0)$ and $\delta(n) = 0\forall n\ne 0$ and $\delta(0) = 1$. The initial condition is used to define the integration constant $C$.

Comment: Does this mean $\rho_{-1} = 0$ and $C = 1$ ? I also thought about that, but something is bothering me.

Comment: Consider to define $G(s,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}s^n\rho_n(t)$